# Hide Specific User Page

Tags: user-roles, user-access

I wanted to know if there were any ways to easily hide a selected user's user page. I've yet to find any code that does so. I've only found code to remove all user pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to hide the author page on the site itself (and not in `wp-admin`).

To do that, just create a new template file called `author-{$id}.php`, where `{$id}` is replaced by the ID of the author you want to hide. So if the author ID is `6`, the template file should be called `author-6.php`.

Inside the new file, put this in:

```
<?php
header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );
wp_redirect( get_home_url() );
exit;
?>
```

Now when you try to load the author's page, it will just redirect to the site visitor to your home page.

([Source](http://blog.futtta.be/2015/03/03/quick-tip-disabling-wordpress-author-pages/))

Comment: PS: @Faysal Mahamud's answer is perfect if you wanted to hide the user in `wp-admin`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the user in user list page. The following working for you.

//yousiteurl/wp-admin/users.php

Here is the code which hides specific user. It is tested and working fine.

Add this in functions.php in your theme.

**functions.php**

//change user-14 to your user id.

```
<?php 
  add_action('admin_head' , 'ft_hide_administrator_user');
    function ft_hide_administrator_user(){
      global $pagenow;
      if ( 'users.php' == $pagenow ){
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
      }
    ?>
        <style>
          #user-14{display:none;}
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript' >
          jQuery(document).ready(function(){
          //jQuery('#user-14').remove(); // to remove users.php list page html
          jQuery('#user-14').hide(); // to hide users.php list page html
            var total_count = jQuery(".users-php .subsubsub li.all .count").text();
            total_count = total_count.substring(1, total_count.length - 1) - 1;
            jQuery('.users-php .subsubsub li.all .count').text('('+total_count+')');


            var total_count = jQuery(".users-php .subsubsub li.administrator .count").text();
            total_count = total_count.substring(1, total_count.length - 1) - 1;
            jQuery('.users-php .subsubsub li.administrator .count').text('('+total_count+')');

          });
        </script>
        <?php
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use [`pre_user_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_query/) filter and modify or adjust the `where` query.
Something like the following code:

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', function( $uqi ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $uqi->query_where .=  ' AND id != 1';
});
```